# How to insert data into a PL/SQL table type rather than PL/SQL table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table TDATAMAP which has around 10 million records, I want to fetch all the records into a PL/SQL table type variable, match it with some criteria and finally insert all the required records in a staging table. Please tell me if its possible to do it using PL/SQL table typle variable and BULK INSERT/COLLECT . I am also concerned about the performance of the code.

Comment: what do you mean "match it with some criteria" exactly?  I think there is a much better way to do what you want, but not enough info to tell.  Can u give some sample code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, but you probably should not, load 10 million records into memory at once - as long as there is sufficient memory to hold that much.  Normally BULK COLLECT is used with the LIMIT clause to process a finite number of rows at a time e.g. 1000.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm):

> The BULK COLLECT clause lets you fetch entire columns from the result
>   set, or the entire result set at once. The following example,
>   retrieves columns from a cursor into a collection:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE NameList IS TABLE OF emp.ename%TYPE;
   names NameList;
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE job = 'CLERK';
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO names;
   ...
   CLOSE c1;
END;
```

> The following example uses the LIMIT clause. With each iteration of
>   the loop, the FETCH statement fetches 100 rows (or less) into index-by
>   table acct_ids. The previous values are overwritten.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE NumList IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT acct_id FROM accounts;
   acct_ids NumList;
   rows NATURAL := 100;  -- set limit
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      /* The following statement fetches 100 rows (or less). */
      FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO acct_ids LIMIT rows;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      ...
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Answer (score 8):

> " I want to fetch all the records into a PL/SQL table type variable,
>   match it with some criteria and finally insert all the required
>   records in a staging table."

This may well not be the right approach to take.  SQL is a *set-based* programming language.  It has features which allow us to identify and work with just the set of records we want.

So, instead of a three stage process - extract, filter, insert - celebrate the joy of sets:

```
insert into your_staging_table 
select whatver
from your_10m_table
where something = your_matching_criteria;
```

There will be scenarios when this is not good enough.  But this is the approach to start with.