# Oracle: insert from type table

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, bulkinsert

i want to insert from a type of table into a table.

Is there a way to do this with bulk? And can I change the type table content a little?

Just like here, but the other way around:
[How to insert data into a PL/SQL table type rather than PL/SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227407/how-to-insert-data-into-a-pl-sql-table-type-rather-than-pl-sql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have something like

```
CREATE TYPE my_nested_table_type
    AS TABLE OF <<something>>;

DECLARE
  l_nt my_nested_table_type;
BEGIN
  <<something that populates l_nt>>
```

then the way to do a bulk `insert` of the data from the collection into a heap-organized table would be to use a `FORALL`

```
FORALL i in 1..l_nt.count
  INSERT INTO some_table( <<list of columns>> )
    VALUES( l_nt(i).col1, l_nt(i).col2, ... , l_nt(i).colN );
```

Comment: thanks, i was using "FOR i IN 1 .. DATA.COUNT LOOP". is there any difference between "FORALL i in 1..DATA.COUNT" and my old solution? is the keyword FORALL really faster?

Comment: @Fulley - The `FORALL` does a bulk bind of the data.  The `FOR` does not.  The `FORALL` eliminates the extra context shifts between SQL and PL/SQL.  That may or may not result in meaningful performance impacts.  It will depend on what fraction of your program execution is taken up with these context shifts

Comment: @JustinCave - Do you know since when this is possible? As far as I remember in earlier Oracle releases `FORALL` was possible only for _simple_ table types like `... AS TABLE OF NUMBER` but not for record types like `... AS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE`, for example.

Comment: @Wernfried - Are you talking about collections defined in PL/SQL?  I'm pretty sure since the advent of `FORALL` that you've been able to use any SQL collection type whether a collection of scalars or of objects.

Comment: @JustinCave - You are right, the collection type is defined inside a PL/SQL block and even as `Associative array`, not a `Nested table`